# using markov chains to solve a project-euler problem?

Tags: probability, project-euler

I never learned what markov chain is, but from googling it seems like if there are finite states and each state has probabilities to jump to other states, I can use markov chain.

What I'm on is http://projecteuler.net/problem=227, the chase.

> "The Chase" is a game played with two dice and an even number of
>   players.
>
> The players sit around a table; the game begins with two opposite
>   players having one die each. On each turn, the two players with a die
>   roll it. If a player rolls a 1, he passes the die to his neighbour on
>   the left; if he rolls a 6, he passes the die to his neighbour on the
>   right; otherwise, he keeps the die for the next turn. The game ends
>   when one player has both dice after they have been rolled and passed;
>   that player has then lost.
>
> In a game with 100 players, what is the expected number of turns the
>   game lasts?
>
> Give your answer rounded to ten significant digits.

N people sit around a table, so I name them 1, 2 ... 100 clockwise.( or counterclockwise, which doesn't matter) person 1 and 51 have the dice at beginning.

From description, given N people, state (A, B) is person A and person B having dice. They can move to state(A+1, B), state(A, B+1), state(A+1, B+1) ... state(A-1, B-1). There are 8 distinct states that at least one die changes its owner. I can calculate all the next states and probabilities of them for each state.

say probability (a, b) is the probability of finishing a game if person a and b has the dice. if a=b, which is condition of the game to finish, probability (a, b) = 1. if not a=b, I made a function to find the probability :

> if a=b then return 1.
>
> if not a=b,
>
> ```
> for each next-state from (a, b):
>    add up (probability of moving to a next-state)*(probability of ending game in that state)
> ```

so this function will recursively search for whether game could be ended in that state.

My concern is that above function could get into endless recursion. for example -

start with (1, 10) -> from this state game can't be done in one turn, so I search -- (0, 10), (2, 11) ... I keep searching until I hit (a, b) that a=b. say I am in the middle of search, ended up in (4, 5) and game can be ended in (5, 5). moving from (4, 5) to (5, 5) has P probability. but for (1-P) probability, I have to keep searching.

I think there is something I missing about probabilities or I really don't know about markov chain. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@did, I really appreciate your help. your idea of dividing states by distance, not by the index of players holding the dice, reduced case from ~10000 to 51.

I eventually solved this problem. First, I divided every state of the game into distance between two dice - $d$, for distance, is $ 0 \le d \le 50$

I built precise probability table for transition between $d_n $to $d_m$. This can be done by simple programming with only 50 loops. for instance, probability table for $d_{29}$ is :

{27: 0.027777777777777776, 28: 0.2222222222222222, 29: 0.5, 30: 0.2222222222222222, 31: 0.027777777777777776}

than, for each state $d_n$, we need the expected number of plays to reduce distance between two dice. That is given as a linear multivariable equation. for $d_{29}$, the $E(29)$ is : $$ E(29) = 1 + 0.02777777777777777E(27) + 0.2222222222222222E(28) + 0.5E(29) + 0.2222222222222222E(30) + 0.027777777777777776E(31) $$

and $E(0) = 0$. with this 51 equations, I used linear algebra to solve E(1) to E(50). By the way, the expected plays required ( $E(50)$ ) was less than 3800, peculiarly less than did suggested.

Comment: some hints who are trying to solve this problem: if only ten players are involved, the expected plays required rounded to ten significant digits is 40.56192661

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a complete solution.*

A Markov chain approach is based on the distance $X_t$ from the position of the first die to the position of the second die after $t\geqslant0$ games are played. With $2N$ players around the table, $X_0=N$, $0\leqslant X_t\leqslant N$ for every $t\geqslant0$, and one wants to compute the mean of  the first hitting time of $0$, defined as $T=\inf\{t\geqslant0\mid X_t=0\}$.

Let $\mathfrak X=\{0,1,\ldots,N\}$. For every state $x$ in $\mathfrak X$, the transitions with positive probabilities are from $x$ to those $x+z$ with $-2\leqslant z\leqslant2$ such that $x+z$ is again in $\mathfrak X$.

The next step would be to write down precisely these transition probabilities and to deduce $\mathbb E(T)$.

A second approach is to count the distance $\bar X_t$ clockwise, then $0\leqslant \bar X_t\leqslant 2N$ and one considers $\bar T=\inf\{t\geqslant0\mid \bar X_t\in\{0,2N\}\}$. If the site $x$ is in the middle, so to speak, that is, if $\bar X_t=x$ with $2\leqslant x\leqslant 2N-2$, then the displacement is distributed as the sum of two i.i.d. random variables each with distribution $\frac16(\delta_{-1}+4\delta_0+\delta_1)$. Hence, $\bar X_{t+1}=\bar X_t+\xi$ where $\mathbb P(\xi=+2)=\mathbb P(\xi=-2)=\frac1{36}$,  $\mathbb P(\xi=+1)=\mathbb P(\xi=-1)=\frac8{36}$, and $\mathbb P(\xi=0)=\frac12$.

Noting that $\mathbb E(\xi^2)=\frac23$, one sees that $M_t=\bar X_t^2-\frac23t$ is *almost* a martingale, hence a natural conjecture is that $\mathbb E(\bar T)\approx\frac32(\mathbb E(X_T^2)-N^2)$. Since $\bar X_T$ is uniform on $\{0,2N\}$ by symmetry, this yields $\mathbb E(T)\approx\frac92N^2$.

For $100$ players, $N=50$ hence this heuristics suggests that the expected number of turns is $\approx11,250$.